# Stack Trace is missing for uncaught python exceptions

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7.3 and runtime exceptions are suddenly generating the following type of error instead of the usual, handy stack trace.

```
(<class 'NameError'>, NameError("name 'window' is not defined"), <traceback object at 0x24857260>)
```

If I can't find the error based on the object name, I'm forced to add a bunch of print statements to isolate it. This is sub-optimum. I initially contacted PyCharm support regarding this but it's related to the Python instance and not the IDE so they were no help other than to tell me to "Google it". Most of what I've found on line tells me how to catch explicit exceptions via a try-catch block. But that would force me to add a bunch of try-catch blocks everywhere which were never required before when runtime errors simply spit out a stack trace complete with module and line numbers. I suspect there is some way of resolving the module/line based on the hex traceback address? But I just want my trusty stack trace back! Thanks!

---

Simply surrounding the code of the main module as follows fixed the first problem.

```
try:
   
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   app.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 12))
   window = MyWindow()
   ...
    
except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

I now get stack traces on runtime errors.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Are you modifying the traceback module at any point in your code? That would seem to be the only thing that would cause this

Comment: @KieranWood: Not intentionally. Can an imported module modify it?

Comment: It shouldn't but, Absolute worse comes to worst you can typically manually print this info using https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc